# Float, transformations in css

Tags: html, css

Please see this Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/73g7t/
I am not clear about some of the things in it.

1. DIV is a block level element(so it starts and ends with a line break). Then why are the divs placed side by side? Does float remove the line breaks of block level elements?
2. In the definition of `.wrapper div`, the code for rotate - `transform: rotate(15deg);` is already present. Then why is there another `transform: rotate` in `.wrapper .translate` **BUT** not in`.wrapper .transform-origin`

Comment: Block level elements **DO NOT** start and end with a line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) explains why this is.  It's not a line-break, but the [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) is restarted for `float`s.
2. `.wrapper .translate` overwrites the `transform` rules.  If it does not specify `rotate`, the rotation would not occur: http://jsfiddle.net/73g7t/304/ -- `transform-origin` is a separate rule.

Comment: In the definition of "div hover" only the rotate is  transformed to 0degs. How does the red box come back to it's original position even though you have not mentioned the translate to become 0?

Comment: @Ashwin `transform` (and its ilk) is a *rule*.  It can have only one definition.  A ruleset with higher specificity overrides the *entire* rule.  You can have `transform: rotate skew scale translate` in one ruleset and `transform: rotate(0deg)` in one with higher specificity and *only* the latter one is applied

Comment: Thanks! I am clear now with the second question. But I still do not understand answer to the 1st question. What so you mean  by "block formatting context is restarted for floats"?

Comment: Essentially, when you `float` `display: block` elements they don't stack vertically as long as there is room for them horizontally